# Weighted sampling without replacement and negative weights

Tags: algorithm, math, statistics, probability, random

I have an unusual sampling problem that I'm trying to implement for a Monte Carlo technique. I am aware there are related questions and answers regarding the fully-positive problem.

I have a list of n weights w_1,...,w_n and I need to choose k elements, labelled s_1,...,s_k say. The probability distribution that I want to sample from is

p(s_1,...,s_k) = |w_s_1 + ... + w_s_k| / P_total

where P_total is a normalization factor (the sum of all possible p(s,...) without P_total). I don't really care about how the elements are ordered for my purpose.

Note that some of the w_i may be less than zero and the absolute magnitude signs above. With purely non-negative w_i this distribution is relatively straightforward by sampling without replacement - a tree method being the most efficient as far as I can tell. With some negative weights, though, I feel like I must resort to explicitly writing out each possibility and sampling from this exponentially large set. Any suggestions or insights would be appreciated!

Comment: `p(s_1,...,s_k) = |w_s_1 + ... + w_s_k| / P_total` That's gonna get you a probability space much larger than 1. Did you mean |W_s_1 * w_s_2 * ... * w_s_k|  or some other variation?

Comment: For example, choose 2 out of 3 with w_1=w_2=w_3 = 1/3.
P(s_1,s_2) = P(s_2,s_3) = P(s_1,s_3) = 2/3, and their sum is 2.

Comment: P_total is designed to take care of the normalization. In your case P_total is 2/3 + 2/3 + 2/3 = 2. Each p(s) is divided by two, so you get 1/3, 1/3 and 1/3.

Comment: A non-trivial example is w_1 = 1, w_2 = 0.1 and w_3 = -0.1. Then the unnormalized weights are p(1,2) = 1.1, p(1,3) = 0.9, and p(2,3) = 0. The sum of these is P_total = 2. The normalized weights are therefore p(1,2) = 0.55, p(1,3) = 0.45 and p(2,3) remains 0.

Comment: An algorithm for computing the normalization factor would suffice (but I don't have one offhand).

Comment: How big are n and k? What precision do you need for the weights? I mean, if the weights are arbitrary floats to begin with, could you truncate them to a fixed point representation, and how many digits would that need?

Comment: It's not exactly exponentially big, the set's size is C(n,k) obviously. But I can't see how to get around computing them all because of the absolute value, even if you'd have P_total beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

Rejection sampling is worth a try. Compute the maximum weight of a sample (max of the abs of each of the k least and k greatest). Repeatedly generate a uniform random sample and accept it with probability equal to its weight over the maximum weight until a sample is accepted.

Comment: Right... nice idea! I might modify it to be more efficient by beginning with the algorithm for positive weights (taking absolute values) and rejecting samples with probability 1 - ratio of the sample's weights without and with absolute values. Since I *expect* the negative weights to be relative small, the rejection rate should be small.